# How do I deal with a double linefeed in copy-pasted user input?

Tags: c

So I have this code:

```
void read_string(char *dest, int size) {
    fgets(dest, size, stdin);
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(dest); i++)
        if(dest[i]=='\n')
            dest[i]='\0';
}

int main() {
    char arr[1000][64];
    int i=0;
    while(i<1000) {
        printf("Enter filename: ");
        read_string(arr[i], 62);
        if(strlen(arr[i])==0)
            break;
        i++;
    }
}
```

However, if I copy a string such as:

```
a


(excluding this line)
```

...and paste it into the command prompt, the output is as follows:

> Enter filename: a
>
> Enter filename:

The loop breaks and the program goes on. My desired outcome in that situation would be for the program to break the loop **without** displaying the next "Enter filename" message. However, if the user ends their input with a single linefeed, the loop should simply continue.

I'm aware why it doesn't work like intended in that form, but I'm out of ideas at this point. Whatever I try to do, it still works the same.

In case you're wondering why I want it to work in such a weird way, this is a part of my homework assignment, completely unrelated to the main purpose of the exercise. However, my program is failing a unit test because of this.

Comment: Is testing copy-pasted input part of your test case?

Comment: `fgets` can't get a double-newline: it stops at the first newline or at size limit. Here is an easy way to [Remove trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: Oh, I think I see: the remaining input is presented to the next loop. So you could filter unsatisfactory input (such as a single newline) and skip to the next loop – just as you would if the user only presses "Enter".

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a magic way to distinguish between a pasted newline character and a typed by hand newline character. There isn't any.